# Incorrect attribute value type count.index is a number

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

how to pass security group value in lb resource terraform v1.3.1

`security_groups = "${element(aws_security_group.lb_security_group.*.id,count.index)}","${split(",",var.cloudfront_sg_id)}"`

working fine in terraform v0.11.11
i need actual syntax in terraform v1.3.1

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: It would also help to include the entire error message rather than just the hint about the values of variables in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I can see is you are using the resource along with the count index.
For count.index, terraform refers to the **data** module and not the **resource** module.

so, Now what you can do here is you need to inject data into the **data** module and then use that data module of sg with count index.